# Cannot install certificates. Error: "Private key required to install a certificate"

Tags: wi-fi, certificates

I am trying to download and install a certificate to use my workplace's wifi. I have a Pixel 2 running Android 11. I took these steps to install the certificate as intended: I Download the file, go through Settings > Security > Encryption & credentials > Install a certificate > Wifi certificate, and select the downloaded cert. This kicks me back a screen displaying a toast that reads "Private key required to install a certificate." I've contacted Google support on this issue, and this was their response:

Due to security vulnerability reasons, the option to bypass the CA Certificate validation for enterprise networks has been recently removed from Pixel. In this case, we'd recommend you to reach out to your local network administrator to explore the alternate options in connecting to their Wifi network. For more information please refer to this link https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/pixel/2020-12-01

I realize this may mean I'm out of luck, but still, I'd like to ask if anyone has any suggestions, workarounds, or suitable alternatives. I haven't asked a question on here before, so I hope I'm in the right place. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you have chose the wrong category. On Android a "Wifi certificate" is a certificate with private key used for WPA1/2/3 enterprise authentication by using a certificate (EAP-TLS). If you just want to install a trusted certificate without private key select "CA certificate". The newly installed root-CA certificate should then also be available in the Wifi WPA enterprise CA-cert settings.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If I try to install the certificate as a CA certificate, I click "Install anyway" at the warning and select my certificate, but am met with the same error message.

Comment: In what file type did you got the "Wifi certificate" you are trying to install (crt/cer/der file or PEM file with text content)? Because CA certificate installation on Android 11 works, I have just tested it.

Comment: It's unedited name after the download is "https_interception_ca_certificate.crt". 

I believe you, I've successfully installed them in the past as well. Recently resetting my wireless settings forced me to reinstall this certificate, but I am met with the above error.

Comment: The file name sounds not like a Wifi certificate for authentication, instead if seems to be an network interception certificate from a proxy. Even if you install it, it will only be valid for Chrome, apps ignore such installed certificates by default (-> no network connection for apps). CA certificates that are accepted by all apps can only be installed on rooted devices. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730978/some-androids-apps-wont-connect-through-fiddler/62731432#62731432

Comment: Ok, thank you, that looks like a really complete answer. I don't want to be picky, but at this point, even just being able to use Chrome would be great. Do you think there is there anything I can do to just get it installed?

Comment: As it is a public certificate there is no reason to keep the certificate secret. So if you could upload it somewhere we could check if the problem is the certificate. Because on my Pixel 3 running Android 11 (but not with the latest security updates) certificates can be installed without problems.

Comment: Though I am reasonably confident it's not the certificate, that would be great, thank you. How would you prefer I share it?

Comment: Certificates are so small, just upload it somewhere and post the link.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N-aNvKeWIGKvf1DbJvM4WEVICCEyyp1H/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The file is a regular X.509 certificate just as you would expect. Could be really a bug in Android preventing the installation. Google in the last months is good in adding new bugs...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was hoping to avoid, but if that's it then that's it. Thank you very much for your help, you've been kind and knowledgeable.